# How do you find documents that do not match across 2 collections in ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have 2 collections in ArangoDB. You can imagine their contents as follows:

Collection A: ["a", "b", "c"]
Collection B: ["b", "c"]

I'm trying to write a query that will return documents that do not match across the 2 collections.
What query do I write to get the document "a"?
I have tried:
FOR doc1 IN A
FOR doc2 IN B
FILTER doc1.word != doc2.word
LIMIT 10
RETURN doc1

But that actually returns rows that are similar.
What am I doing wrong?